# How to replace multiple nil checks for a nested hash in a single statement/check?

Tags: ruby

I am getting a response by making an API call and the value I am interested in is:

`JSON.parse(response).first['property/details']['result']['assessment']`

`JSON.parse(response)` gives an array, I pick the first hash element and go through the nested hashes in it to get the required value.

The problem is, there can be a nil in any of the values which would break the code and so I have to do something like:

```
if property=JSON.parse(response).first
     if property['property/details']
         if result=property['property/details']['result']
             # get the value result['assessment']
         end
     end
end
```

This seems very cumbersome and I would like to do this with as few lines as possible, ideally one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-dig) is your friend:

```
JSON.parse(response).dig(0, 'property/details', 'result', 'assessment')
```

You can pass both, indices and keys to traverse nested array / hash structures.

Comment: You may wish to also reference [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig), [Struct#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Struct.html#method-i-dig) and [OpenStruct#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-dig).

Answer (score 2):

While I dig @Stefan's answer, if there is a need to support Ruby versions prior to 2.3 (when `dig` made its debut), the following can be used:

```
ops = [0, 'property/details', 'result', 'assessment'].
ops.reduce(JSON.parse(response)) { |memo, s| memo && memo[s] }
```